# Resolving ambiguity in dangling else

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsing, ambiguity

Initially the ambiguous grammar is as follows (with some cropped production rules):

```
<STMT>         -->  <IF-THEN> | <IF-THEN-ELSE>
<IF-THEN>      -->  if condition then <STMT>
<IF-THEN-ELSE> -->  if condition then <STMT> else <STMT>
```

To resolve the ambiguity, the previous grammar is transformed into the following one in the book I study:

```
<STMT>           -->  <IF-THEN> | <IF-THEN-ELSE>
<IF-THEN>        -->  if condition then <STMT>
<IF-THEN-ELSE>   -->  if condition then <E-STMT> else <STMT>
<E-STMT>         -->  <E-IF-THEN-ELSE>
<E-IF-THEN-ELSE> -->  if condition then <E-STMT> else <E-STMT>
```

What I cannot get is that why the following rule is necessary.

```
<E-IF-THEN-ELSE> -->  if condition then <E-STMT> else <E-STMT>
```

As far as I think about, the update on `<IF-THEN-ELSE>` and introduction of `<E-STMT>` is sufficient to resolve the ambiguity. Could you please give an example refuting my argument? Thanks..

Comment: It would seem that your *language* is ambiguous. For `if A then if B then P else Q` it is not clear where the `else` should belong. Note that most languages solve this by having `end`, `fi` or `{ ... }` as delimiters. (I don't see how the second grammar solves anything. Did you crop too much?)

Comment: Not really... To produce your example you have to follow `<STMT> --> <IF-THEN> --> <STMT> --> <IF-THEN-ELSE> --> <E-STMT>`. You cannot execute `<STMT> --> <IF-THEN-ELSE> --> ...` Because, `<IF-THEN-ELSE>` mandates derivation with `<E-STMT>` which mandates a closing else for an if clause.

Comment: So the second grammar does not allow `else`-free inner conditionals? That seems odd, and is also not what the first grammar does.

Comment: @Raphael Using <IF-ELSE> sequentially it is possible. However, the aim is to associate else clauses with the closest if clauses. So, you are right; the meaning changes. But it is accepted in this case considering the aim. I just cannot understand the necessity of <E-IF-THEN-ELSE>. I could not produce an example requiring the introduction of this rule.

Comment: @Raphael This is pretty much like the problem of operator precedence in
arithmetic expressions. The simplest is an ambiguous grammar, but
specific non-terminals such as TERM or FACTOR are used to impose a
specific shape of the parse tree.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that one can also derive some atomic statements from `<STMT>` and `<E-STMT>`, otherwise the language of both grammars would be empty and all would be quite trivial. :-) But that aside:

The new grammar should do two things: it should be unambiguous and it should generate the same language.

The variables `<E-STMT>` and `<E-IF-THEN-ELSE>` are introduced to remember part of the context in which the variable occurs. What you want to accomplish, is that the variables `<STMT>`, `<IF-THEN>` and `<IF-THEN-ELSE>` cannot occur in a position directly preceeding an `else` symbol, and also that the variables `<E-STMT>` and `<E-IF-THEN-ELSE>` *must* occur in a position directly preceeding an `else` symbol. So, if we see a `<E-STMT>` or `<E-IF-THEN-ELSE>` somewhere, we know that the next symbol must be `else`, and if we see an other variable we know that the next symbol cannot be an `else`. This way we have some week form of "context-awareness".

If we remove the rule for `<E-IF-THEN-ELSE>` and replace the rule for `<E-STMT>` by

```
<E-STMT> -> <IF-THEN-ELSE>
```

then we can derive the following:

> `<STMT>` $\to$ 
>   `<IF-THEN-ELSE>` $\to$ 
>   `if condition then <E-STMT> else <STMT>` $\to$ 
>   `if condition then <E-IF-THEN-ELSE> else <STMT>` $\to$ 
>   `if condition then if condition then <E-STMT> else <STMT> else <STMT>`

and here a `<STMT>` variable which directly preceeds an `else` symbol. This will lead to ambiguities.

If we try to fix this and additionally change the if-then-else rule to

```
<IF-THEN-ELSE> --> if condition then <E-STMT> else <E-STMT>
```

then we can perform the derivation

> `<STMT>` $\to$ `<IF-THEN-ELSE>` $\to$ `if condition then <E-STMT> else <E-STMT>`

and here we have an `<E-STMT>` variable without a following `else` symbol. Since the `<E-STMT>` generates no if statements without else clause, the language of the new grammar is not the same.

The grammar which was proposed in the book solves both these problems.

Comment: "it should be unambiguous and it should generate the same language" -- in the context of compilers, it should also generate the same (up to minor changes) syntax trees.